# NuGet Framework Targeting in Squirrel

Tags: nuget, squirrel.windows

I'm trying to better understand the proper use of .NET Framework version targeting in the project's NuSpec file, as relates to Squirrel.

For example:

```
<file src="bin\Release\*.dll" target="lib\net472\"></file>
```

Does the version specified here affect Squirrel's operations at all? Or is it a NuGet-specific construct only?

What does it mean when we say [.NET 4.8](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/commit/b2d092b5507f01813a2e9b73b889e73bf59ee2a7) is now supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior by NuGet is driven by the compatibility map of the frameworks.
.NET Framework is *mostly* backwards compatible, so NuGet has built on top of that, when your package declares that it targets net472, net48 as the next evolution is acceptable.
NuGet will allow this package to be consumed in .NET Framework 4.8 projects.

See [more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/version-compatibility) for .NET Framework version compatibility.

See [more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library-guidance/cross-platform-targeting) on cross platform targeting libraries, which talks about the multi targeting concept.

Comment: So from this, the construct would seem to be independent from the inner workings of Squirrel. Would you tend to agree?

Comment: Yes, it's a NuGet specific concept.